# Safe method for database calls between client-side and server-side in JAVA & Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, ejb, ejb-3.0, servlet-3.0

i am builds a java chat application , based on **Java Secure Sockets** and **JavaFX** and use Derby Database on the server side to record the members in the database ,

My Question is , how i make a secure connection between the Client Side Applet and the Server Side ? instead of the direct connection to the remote database from the client side to the server side ?

i had an idea to use **Servlet** as a Remote API , and calling it from the client side , and tell it the command to run it in the remote database on the server ?

Is this method Safe and Secure ?
but i am worry about that may a bad people try to fetch the API URL , and try to call it badly and add wrong records to the database without needs to login the client-side application and try to hack the database ? so how i secure my self from this matter ? with notice that the client-side Application may be installed in many computers , so don't tell me to secure the API by determine the remote IP which capable to connect via the API :)

And if there are any other more secure methods please tell me

Thank you ,

Answer (score 0):

Your application seems to be a good candidate for a standard [three-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). Using servlets as a proxy between your client and the DB is a good and widely used approach. Among other benefits it allows you to use a higher level transport (HTTP) instead of dealing with sockets. You can create a simple REST API to handle client requests and call it from your client. I believe, it will also make the client code simpler.

> Is this method Safe and Secure?

Yes. You can use HTTPS for traffic encryption and HTTP basic authentication to protect from unauthorized calls to your service. These security features are a part of the servlet specification. Alternatively you can use other frameworks (like Spring) for it.